# How do I call a librosa function on the entire audio file?

Tags: python, arrays, audio, data-science, librosa

I have short audio files which I'm trying to analyze using Librosa, in particular the spectral centroid function.  However, this function outputs an array of different values representing the spectral centroid at different frames within the audio file.  [The documentation](https://librosa.org/doc/0.8.0/generated/librosa.feature.spectral_centroid.html) says that the frame size can be changed by specifying the parameter `n_fft` when calling the function.  It would be more beneficial to me if this function analyzed the entire audio file at once rather than outputting the result at multiple points in time.  Is there a way for me to specify that I want the function to be called with, say, a frame size of the *entire* audio file instead of the default time which is 2048 samples?  Is there another better way?

Cheers and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of the FFT window (`n_fft`) specifies not only how many samples you need, but also the frequency resolution of the result (longer `n_fft`, better resolution). To ensure comparable results for many files you probably want to use the same `n_fft` value for all of them.

With that out of the way, say your files all have no more than 16k samples. Then you may still achieve a reasonable runtime (FFT runs in [*O(N log N)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)). Obviously, this will get worse as your file size increases. So you could call `spectral_centroid(y=y, n_fft=16384, hop_length=16384, center=False)` and because `hop_length` is set to the same value as `n_fft` you would compute the FFT for non-overlapping windows. And because `n_fft` is greater than the max number of samples in all your files (in this example), you should get only one value. Note that I set `center` to `False` to avoid an adjustment that is not necessary for your scenario.

Alternatively to choosing a long transform window, you could also compute many values for overlapping windows (or frames) using the [STFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform) (which is what librosa does anyway) and simply average the resulting values like this:

```
import numpy as np
import librosa

y, sr = librosa.load(librosa.ex('trumpet'))
cent = librosa.feature.spectral_centroid(y=y, sr=sr, center=False)
avg_cent = np.mean(cent)
print(avg_cent)

2618.004809523263
```

The latter solution is in line with what is usually done in [MIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_information_retrieval) and my recommendation. Note that this also allows you to use other statistics functions like the *median*, which may or may not be something you are interested in. In other words, you can determine the *distribution* of the centroids, which arguably carries more meaning.